# contact report with custom field as section heading

Tags: reports, custom-reports

I have a custom field, "Location" with 10 values. There are a variable number of Mentors at each location. I'm trying to get a report that, for each location, has Location as section heading, following by the number of Mentors at that location and then a list of those Mentors.

If I do not choose the Location as a column in the report, my first section heading is Location: 1 (16).

If I select Location as a column, I get Location: Miami (). Plus I have a column repeating the value "Miami" which is not useful.

The section heading I want is: Location: Miami (16)

Is there a simple way to accomplish this or does it require code?

Answer (score 0):

There was https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20752 but I don't think it fully fixed it everywhere, so the short answer is it might require some code. But maybe the fix and discussion there will give some pointers.